# 404: Page not found after apply SUPEE-14015 patch

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 version, after applying patch for my magento website, i got this error in every page:

[image]

Comment: Quick and dirty troubleshoot. Disable third party extension, just renamed all the 3rd party extensions inside app/etc/models to end as -disabled such as companyname_extension.xml-disabled  Then drop(or rename) var/cache and var/session folders and reload. This should bring the site back up assuming it is related to an extension, then you can enable one extension at a time and until you locate the ones causing the issue.

Comment: This link https://magentary.com/kb/magentos-404-error-page-not-found-in-default-design-after-supee-10415/ worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

"404: Page Not Found" error show from the errors/ directory after upgrading to SUPEE-10415. **This issue occurs only in Magento installations that run certain third-party extensions.**

**Workaround by Magento:** Confirm that there are no PHP warnings generated by any of the extensions or customizations.

in short, its a problem with one of the extensions you have.

you can read more in official release.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html